# How to get a file integrity error with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have an invalid csv file:

```
A,B,C,D
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
9,,
```

As you can see the last row has only 3 values, but count of columns is 4. In this case if I do `pandas.read_csv(file)` I don't get an error, and pandas set `NaN` for last row in column D:

```
>>> df.iloc[2].to_dict()
{'A': 9.0, 'B': nan, 'C': nan, 'D': nan}
```

Is there any way to get an error during read_csv() function if file is invalid?
Thanks in advance!

**UPD**: Chek if NaN value is exist and raise an error - doesn't solve my problem, because as you can see in last row in B column I already have NaN value and it is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the way *read_csv* processes empty fields,
but you can compute the number of *NaN* values in your
DataFrame:

```
nNaN = df.isna().sum().sum()
```

Then, if *nNaN > 0*, you can raise some exception or process
such case any way you wish.

I think that *read_csv* alone is not able to tell apart cases like:

- no value between adjacent commas,
- too little input fields.

To circumvent this limitation, you can:

- read your input file as a DataFrame with a **single** column
  (passing a non-existing char as *sep*),
- compute occurrences of a comma in each row,
- take unique values from them,
- check whether there is only one unique value (all rows
  have the same number of commas).

The code to do it is:

```
wrk = pd.read_csv('Input.csv', sep='|', names=['xx'])
wrk.xx.str.count(',').unique().size > 1
```

The downside of this solution is that you read your input file:

- first time, only to check whether it contains too little fields
  in any row (and raise some exception if it does),
- second time - "normal" reading.

Comment: thanks, but this doens't solve my problem, check my update

Answer (score 1):

The file isnt technically invalid. But you can use the fact that pandas replaces missing values with NA. Something like this might work for what you want:

```
# read in the CSV
df = pandas.read_csv('mydata.csv')

# check if the sum of the number of NA values in the dataframe
if nNaN = df.isna().sum().sum() != 0 :
    # if the sum is not 0, then print out a warning. 
    print("WARNING : This is an invalid dataframe")
```

Comment: *df.isnull().sum()* generates a *Series*.
So to have a **single** answer, whether **any** row contains at least one *NaN*,
you can run: *(df.isnull().sum() != 0).any()*.

Comment: thanks, but this doens't solve my problem, check my update

Comment: thanks @ Valdi_Bo. Edit my answer to reflect your comment.